# How can I have a client-side function in Javascript execute server python and return the result using Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, webserver

I am building a simple webpage using Flask and Javascript. I have a button on my template, and if the user clicks the button, it calls a Javascript function. I am trying to add code so that when that Javascript function executes, it triggers part of my Flask app to do some work and return a result. I want this to be synchronous. I currently have the exact structure I described working with Flask and AJAX for asynchronous server processing:

In my `flask.py` file:

```
@app.route('/server_function')
def do_some_stuff():
    my_Number = 1 + 2 + 3 
    return jsonify(my_Number)
```

And in my `HTML` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function processCodeOnServer() {
            return $.getJSON('/server_function').then(function(data)
            {
                $("#output").text(data);
            });
</script>
```

This does work, but I am using an asynchronous method to process synchronous tasks, and I prefer to my code to execute synchronously so that I can use serial execution to my advantage. I read the Flask tutorials and a textbook on the matter, but I think I'm missing the forest for the trees here. How can accomplish this same code but without jquery / AJAX?

...

Compare

Comment: Submit a form ..?

Comment: You can not make that synchronous.

Comment: Perhaps if you describe why you "prefer to my code to execute synchronously" then perhaps we can suggest some other approach.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Wasn't that explained in the question: "_I prefer to my code to execute synchronously so that I can use serial execution to my advantage._"

Comment: Yes but why do you think a synchronous solution is an advantage? What do you think you can accomplish by having it synchronous?

Comment: If it is synchronous I can allow the client to select an arbitrary number of complex computations from a list, have those computations executed server side, and output each computation's log back to the client in order, without overlapping.

Comment: @Teemu Are you saying what I want to do is commonly done using Flask forms? I have a long history with CLI scripting, but literally no experience with web stuff so that obvious isn't obvious to me.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that, but it's a way to send a synchronous request to your server. You could make a synchronous AJAX request as well (by using native objects and methods), but it is going to be obsoleted at some point in the future. I'd suggest you to take the advantage from asynchronous programming, rather than sticking to the conventional synchronous thinking.